# Document.fullScreen API implementation in Lightning Web Components(LWC)

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, document, html5, dom

I was trying to achieve full screen on an element in Lightning Web Components but was unable to use Document.fullscreen API.

I tried var elem = this.template.querySelector('svg');

```
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
```

But in LWC document component doesn't have particular functions and so was unable to implement full screen functionality.

Please help, I am quiet new in using Lightning Web Components(LWC)...

Answer (score 5):

Locker is currently preventing access to the fullscreen API, not LWC. You can try out the following snippet of javascript in the [Locker console](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console).

```js
document.body.requestFullscreen
// Locker OFF: function requestFullscreen() {[native code]}
// Locker ON: undefined
```